# Visual indication for inline buttons

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a way to show some visual indication that the inline button has been pressed in telegram bot.

I have a bit which send inline keyboard, and when I press each buttons it works perfectly fine, but there is a slight delay in getting response from the server. As there is no visual indication to show if a button has been pressed, it is confusing for uses to know if the button was pressed and end up pressing the same button several times.

Answer (score 3):

there are **different types of [inline buttons](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton)** in Telegram:

- Opens **URL** (with `url`).
- **Forward** a message (with `switch_inline_query`).
- Insert query at the chat (with `switch_inline_query_current_chat`).
- **Button with action** (with `callback_data`).

I suppose you are refering to the last type of button, in that case, if a user press a button **you will get the `callback_data` via [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery)**, and that lets you **modify the original message with [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages) to add something** like:

> Button **TEST** pressed.

Comment: I am getting 'callback_data' when the inline keyboard is pressed. But because in the telegram app there is no indication that the button was pressed, it makes it difficult for the customer to know whether the press has happened or not.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative way, after you got the callback response at your server, you can use Emoji for showing feedback to your users. Just edit the inline message and edit some relative emoji to the button text.